# Customer custom address attribute not save in Magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer-address

We are working on Magento Ver 2.1.8. We have created module for add additional information in customer address. The attribute (other_info) field is display on the the checkout page but not save and display in admin panel.

If we tried to save same attribute value in the admin panel the save it.

Please find the install script....

```
namespace KH\Newaddressattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'other_info', [
            'label' => 'Other info',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'type' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'other_info')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();



    }
}
```